# How to modify nested Laravel collection using group by

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to modify nested collection using group by.

This is sample collection

```
    "document": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "company_id": 4,
            "client_id": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "client": {
                "id": 1,
                "company_id": 4,
                "name": "1663159185735-client"
            },
           "document_items": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "master_id": 5,
                    "text_value": "piyo",
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "master_id": 5,
                    "text_value": "fuga",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "master_id": 3,
                    "text_value": "hoge",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to change like this.

```
    "document": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "company_id": 4,
            "client_id": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "client": {
                "id": 1,
                "company_id": 4,
                "name": "1663159185735-client"
            },
           "document_items": [
                5: [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "master_id": 5,
                    "text_value": "piyo",
                   },
                   {
                    "id": 2,
                    "master_id": 5,
                    "text_value": "fuga",
                   }
                ],
                3: [{
                    "id": 2,
                    "master_id": 5,
                    "text_value": "fuga",
                　　　　　　　}
             　　　　 ]
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I try write below code;

```
        $result->map(function ($v){
            
            $v->documentItems = $v->documentItems->groupBy('master_id');
            return  $v;
        });
```

but output key is `documentItems` not `document_items`

I changed to

```
 $v->document_items = $v->documentItems->groupBy('master_id');
```

key is drawing_drawing_items but not groupby(simple array)

how to modify group by and preserve key case?

Comment: Please provide proper PHP arrays.

Comment: There is `sortBy` method in laravel to group collection by some key. Check out: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby

Comment: `Log::debug($v->documentItems->groupBy('master_id'));` outputs expect array, but can't override document_items key

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> I changed to
>
>  $v->document_items = $v->documentItems->groupBy('master_id');
> key is drawing_drawing_items but not groupby(simple array)
> ```

You should also change like this `$v->document_items->groupBy('master_id')`

The key is 'document_items' not 'documentItems'

Comment: "message": "Call to a member function groupBy() on null",

Comment: I got this error message.